# Display MySQL auto-increment key in App Inventor

Tags: php, auto-increment

I'm currently developing an app for project work. So, after submitting data to MySQL table, how can I setup PHP to display the auto-increment key (confirmation code) of the table for each results submitted? I already have the PHP code for submitting data. I need the code for getting the auto-increment key. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get the current max id, after the inserts, query for all the id's greater than the previous max id

Comment: If I remember correctly, the MySQL PHP driver will return the ID of the inserted row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this depending on what mysql libraries or statements you use in your PHP.

**example 1:**
Perform another query (Not so efficient but works)

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table
```

This will return the highest value in your table (ie the last inserted id)

+1 would give you the next in line AutoIncrement

**example 2:**

Assuming you use default mysql_query in PHP, while the connection is open you can use this:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

if (!$link) {

    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

}

mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");

printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

Whereas *mysql_insert_id()* will return the actual inserted id for your query.

Hope this helps